# how to get the last data using imacros?

Tags: firefox, imacros

i want to get data from elements using imacros
but I want to take the last elements

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=div ATTR=class:"message-text-box" extract=txt
```

TAG POS=1 is the top element
I can't count the last element

any idea ?

```
Browser Firefox 48.0
iMacros for Firefox 8.9.7
Windows 10 32-bit Operating system
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved  :)
this code works

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=class:retry
TAG POS=R-1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:message-text-box EXTRACT=TXT
```

[forum.imacros](https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=31724)

thanks a lot